# How to add additional fields on the base of inputs in django rest framework mongoengine

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-rest-framework, mongoengine

I am developing an `API`, using `django-rest-framework-mongoengine` with `MongoDb`, I want to append additional fields to the request from the `serializer` on the base of user inputs, for example If user enters `keyword`=`@rohit49khatri`, I want to append two more fields to the request by manipulating `keyword`, like `type`=`username`, `username`=`rohit49khatri`

Here's my code:

**Serializer**

```py
class SocialFeedCreateSerializer(DocumentSerializer):
    type = 'username'

    class Meta:
        model = SocialFeedSearchTerm
        fields = [
            'keyword',
            'type',
        ]
        read_only_fields = [
            'type'
        ]
```

**View**

```py
class SocialFeedCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    queryset = SocialFeed.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SocialFeedCreateSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        print(self.request.POST.get('type'))
```

But when I print `type` parameter, It gives `None`

Please help me save some time. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for the additional question: how to get `type` parameter?

```
# access it via `django rest framework request`
self.request.data.get('type', None)
# or via `django request`
self.request.request.POST.get('type', None)
```

for the original question:

situation 1) IMHO for you situation, `perform_create` can handle it:

```
 def perform_create(self, serializer):
     foo = self.request.data.get('foo', None)
     bar = extract_bar_from_foo(foo)
     serializer.save(
         additional_foo='abc',
         additional_bar=bar,
     )
```

situation 2) If you need to **manipulate** it before the data goes to serializer (so that the manipulated data will pass through serializer validation):

```
class SocialFeedCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    queryset = SocialFeed.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SocialFeedCreateSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # you can check the original snipeet in rest_framework/mixin
        # original:  serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        request_data = self.get_create_data() if hasattr(self, 'get_create_data') else request.data
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request_data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)

    def get_create_data(self):
        data = self.request.data.copy()
        # manipulte your data
        data['foo'] = 'foo'
        return data
```

situation 3) If you do need to **manipulate** the request:
(here's just an example, you can try to find out another place to manipulate the request.)

```
class SocialFeedCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    queryset = SocialFeed.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SocialFeedCreateSerializer

    def initial(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # or any other condition you want
        if self.request.method.lower() == 'post':
            data = self.request.data
            # manipulate it 
            data['foo'] = 'foo'
            request._request.POST = data
        return super(SocialFeedCreateAPIView, self).initial(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it in the `serializer` after validation?

Comment: @RohitKhatri situation 1(IMHO for you situation, perform_create can handle it)  is the one after validation....I will update the answer to add the situation order....

Comment: Thank capt, you save my live!